# Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-bootstrap-carousel/dist/react-bootstrap-carousel.css'

Tags: reactjs, heroku, react-bootstrap

I am using Reactjs to writing a web application. It works find when I run npm start on localhost, but it is not working when I deploy and run my repository to Heroku. Heroku open gives me this message `Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-bootstrap-carousel/dist/react-bootstrap-carousel.css' in '/app/src/components/pages'` I have check my GitHub repository that I have this file and also run normally on localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that is because your build doesn’t have the file. Use —copy-files option